# How do you integrate a media player with the Xfce taskbar i.e. for play/stop controls?

Tags: debian, xfce, mediaplayer

In a Debian sid Xfce set-up I'm trying to get the volume control in the taskbar to show the media player controls like it does in some more preconfigured distros. How do I do that? Searches in synaptic and Google have so far turned up nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`xfce4-xmms-plugin`](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-xmms-plugin) or [`xfce4-xfapplet-plugin`](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-xfapplet-plugin) might be what you are looking for. I would expect these to be packaged for Debian, the sources live at [XFCE Goodies](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/).

Comment: Thanks for answering this. However, I reinstalled another system in the end (non-Xfce) and have not been able to check this and won't therefore mark it as correct. I do appreciate your answer though.

Comment: No problem, maybe you'll return to XFCE one day again. :)